# Ternary operator gives "Not a statement" error

Tags: java

Hi below statement throws error . It says **"Not a statement"**

```
map.containsKey(1)? someObject.setFlag(true) : map.put(1,"hello");
```

Is it needed to store the returned value in some variable on the left hand side of the statement?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon. p.s. You can reduce `map.containsKey(1) == true` to `map.containsKey(1)`.

Comment: Try `map.containsKey(1)`. You don't need to compare a boolean value to true. It is already either true or false. Also no semicolon as above.

Comment: added a semi colon and tried with only map.containsKey(1).. still does not work

Comment: @JaredStewart Although that question is related, I don't think the answers are helpful here because the solution is to use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the `Ternary` operator as a `statement`, not an `assignment`. In your case, you should use `if else`

```
if(map.containsKey(1)) {
    someObject.setFlag(true)
}else{
    map.put(1,"hello");
}
```

Here is the java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) of Ternary operator.

Answer (score 7):

The ternary operator is an **expression**, not a statement. It is commonly used to set the value of a variable depending on some condition. In this case, you need to assign the result to a variable in order to make it into a statement:

```
String result = map.containsKey(1) ? someObject.setFlag(true) : map.put(1,"hello");
```

(Note: You should choose a better variable name.)

I think you will still have problems here because `setFlag()` probably doesn't return a `String`. Also, since you are creating side effects, you should replace this with an `if` statement.